# Studying Feynman articles nowadays

Tags: quantum-computer

I'm curious to know if it's useful to study Feynman article "Quantum Mechanical Computer" nowadays. 
I'm a computer scientist, and i don't know any of the literature in quantum computers. Since long time has passed from 1985 it's a waste of time studying that article? If yes, why?

The article can be found at: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/frs119/papers/feynman85_optics_letters.pdf

Thanks.

Comment: It's at least amazing how deeply into technicalities Feynman actually went. At the same moment, I believe that all more modern introductions contain everything from this Feynman article that remained viable.